# Is it legally possible to stand up for getting unfairly marked by my professor?

Tags: united-kingdom, legal-issues, grading

I recently completed my coursework for International Business Strategy in the UK. I have been marked unfairly in a sense where my professor has given me the feedback of not mentioning certain points from the criteria. However, it’s quite evident that I have, for which I have proof and have raised it with him. Yet, he’s quite formidable and blatant towards me on this. I quite evidently wrote about the points he said I haven’t under the umbrella of scholars which used a different term for the words and I provided citations for, which he clearly didn’t see. Anyways, he did say to use simple words which means that he didn’t understand the grammar and marked me low. He has refused to remark me. I am in great disbelief after looking at my results and I want to know what I can do to make it right.

Comment: "_Is it legally possible to_" This is a question you need to ask your lawyer.

Comment: I am not a lawyer. But I believe that (a) all UK universities have documented appeal processes (b) the courts are normally unwilling to consider a case until the university procedures are exhausted. It sounds to me that you have only taken this up informally with the professor; if you want to go further then you need to find out what the procedures are and take advice (adviser, student union, ??) so that you make your case properly and clearly.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, academic judgement is not a matter which you can appeal or take to court. The University / legal system are concerned with whether the formal rules of the assessment are followed. They may take action if there is a systemic bias or discrimination of a group of students. But when it comes to individual pieces of work, neither University nor the judge have enough expertise and time available to remark your work.

Typically, major pieces of assessment (e.g. >50% of your grade) are double-marked or moderated, meaning that someone looked at your professor's marking and checked it. Still, mistakes happen, and sometimes you find your work being marked lower than you expected. This is unpleasant and I am sorry you find yourself in this position. Try to learn from it as much as possible -- even if the learning point is that your professor is not able to appreciate a term used by other scholars and you have to use the term from the class next time. Writing down terminology used in class is definitely an excellent method to prepare for your assessment and ensure that your markers can appreciate all the right points in your work. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You are not going to get legal advise on this forum. For that you need to talk to a legal specialist. But even if it is possible, you need to set your expectations right: A judge is not going to grade your work. It can only look at whether certain rules are followed. It is perfectly possible that your professor did not break such rules, and still got to the conclusion you disagreed with.